# Displaying the value of a string variable in ASP.Net markup

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, markup

Is it possible to take the value from a string variable from a code-behind file and display it in this markup?

```
<h1>People Authorized to Release Children for <TheVariableGoesHere>  </h1>
```

The variable we would like to include is called strForename.

```
Protected Sub GridViewParentsSummary_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridViewParentsSummary.SelectedIndexChanged

    IntParentsID = GridViewParentsSummary.DataKeys(GridViewParentsSummary.SelectedIndex).Value
    strForename = GridViewParentsSummary.DataKeys(GridViewParentsSummary.SelectedIndex).Values("Forename")

    blnAddModeIsSelected = False

    Response.Redirect("AuthorizationForChildReleaseDetails.aspx")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way this would be accomplished is through a code behind method being called.

Something like this for C#

```
<h1>People Authorized to Release Children for <% =this.GetForename() %> </h1>
```

or this for VB.NET

```
<h1>People Authorized to Release Children for <% =Me.GetForename() %> </h1>
```

and in code behind C#

```
protected string GetForename() 
{
    return GridViewParentsSummary.DataKeys(GridViewParentsSummary.SelectedIndex).Values("Forename");
}
```

or in VB.NET

```
Protected Function GetForename() As String
    Return GridViewParentsSummary.DataKeys(GridViewParentsSummary.SelectedIndex).Values("Forename")
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the helpful comments and code samples. In order that I can learn more of what you know, are there any sites I can go to where tips and tricks such as this is listed? Thanks again. :-)

Comment: I can't say that I've learnt more at any site then I have at StackOverflow. Probably the biggest tip I can give you is to look at the top questions for both the month (http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=month) and week (http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=week)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by making your variable protected or public member and using it in the markup like this:

<%#strForename%> Make sure to call DataBind so the field is bound.
I see that you are doing a redirect at the end of your function, You cannot use the variable from page 1 into a redirected page unless you pass it somehow (as a Request parameter or session parameter)
Alternatively you can do a Server.Transfer and pass that in the context